# Is there an Inverse Kinematics Teleop system available anywhere?

Tags: ros, rviz, arm-navigation, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been playing around with the [Planning Components Visualiser](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Automatically%20Generating%20Arm%20Navigation%20Configurations/Planning%20Components%20Visualizer) from the upcoming E-Turtle distribution and I must say, it's very cool. :)

As far as I can see though, it only allows you to preview the results of an IK plan or of posing the joints in a kinematic chain. Ideally what I'd like is to be able to pose my robot in RVIZ using the interactive markers and then press another button that moves my robot to the new pose.

Has anyone written such a system or does someone with connections to Willow Garage know if such a program is planned for inclusion in the forthcoming E-Turtle release?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10624/is-there-an-inverse-kinematics-teleop-system-available-anywhere?/) by [abroun](https://answers.ros.org/users/850/abroun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We are currently developing a more comprehensive tool for interacting with Planning Scenes (the stuff that your robot is trying to not run into) - this tool allows you to create planning scenes, save to and load from a database, create different motion plan requests, generate, save, and visualize trajectories, and send those trajectories to controllers and record the results.   It should be a really neat and powerful tool.  We have a working prototype for the PR2 - we haven't yet made this robot agnostic, but that's a near term goal.

This tool will be released with Electric, but not in the arm_navigation stack - we're not ready to label this a 1.0 tool yet.  Once we've got a release out we'll be adding a tutorial.

And if you have any feedback on tools like the Planning Components Visualizer or the tutorials, we'd love to hear them!

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abroun](https://answers.ros.org/users/850/abroun/) on 2011-07-18**:
That sounds great. I'm currently hacking together a small teleop program for myself that uses the interactive markers and stuff from the PCV. Your Planning tool sounds much more comprehensive though, so whenever you have something ready for public consumption I'd love to have a look. :) Cheers Alan